# Angular2 and window hash location not changing scroll position

Tags: angular, hash, location, window

Using an anchor within an angular 2 components template like

```
<a href="#somewhere">Scroll/Jump to Somewhere</a>
```

results in the route vanishing and reloading the base url with the added window hash location... what am I doing wrong?

**Example**

active route: ''http://localhost:4200/help/test

---> clicking on the above given anchor results in: http://localhost/#somewhere

instead of http://localhost:4200/help/test#somewhere

Comment: I'm pretty sure angular will interpret it as trying to load a route. You should probably scroll programmatically instead.

Comment: Hey...angular fragment concepts helps to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

`<a [routerLink]="['/somewhere']">click to redirect</a>`

Comment: does not change the behaviour